# A prime ideal in the intersection of powers of another ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, field-theory

> Let $K$ be a field. Is it true that for any prime ideal $P$ of the ring $K[[x,y]]$ which   lies properly in the ideal generated by $x$, $y$ we have $P⊆⋂_{n≥0}(x,y)^n$?

My try is to choose the prime ideal generated by $x$. I wanted to show that $x$ can not be in the ideal $(x,y)^2$. But, I am stuck in comparing the powers of $x$ in the two sides of the pop-up equality. Thanks for help!

Comment: If $x\in(x,y)^2$, then $x=x^2f(x,y)+xyg(x,y)+y^2h(x,y)$, and where $x$ could appear in the right hand side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Krull's Intersection Theorem we have $⋂_{n≥0}(x,y)^n=0$. I leave you the pleasure to draw the conclusion.